# Java multidimensional init and loop adding

Tags: java, list

im trying to store a Transient variable as list into model, below are my code:

model part:

```
    private List<String> combinedList = new ArrayList();

    @Transient
    public List<String> getCombinedList() {
        return combinedList;
    }

    public void setCombinedList(List<String> combinedList) {
        this.combinedList = combinedList;
    }
```

action part:

```
for (Map resutlMap : result) {
    myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(new ArrayList()); 
    myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add("a1", util.format(resutlMap.get("obj_Id")), util.format(resutlMap.get("a1_date"))); 
}
```

question:

**1)** i get no suitable method found for add(ArrayList), im not sure how to declare it properly.

**2)** if using the  private List combinedList, do i able store multidimensional value like following?:

```
apple, banana
manggo, carrot
durian, kiwi
```

Comment: `add(new ArrayList());` what do you expect this to do? your list is a list of string, you can't add an array in it.

Comment: im trying to adding string actually

Comment: well, `new ArrayList()` is not exactly how you create a string, I assume you realize that?

Comment: if i try something like this: myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(new List<String>());  it say: List is abstract cannot be instantiated.

Comment: tried myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xx", "xx","xx")));  not working either

Comment: why are you trying to add a list, rather than a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Question number 1:**

I believe you want to set an ArrayList to your combineList. In that case you need to use

```
myJjjModel.setCombinedList(new ArrayList());
```

or

```
myJjjModel.getCombinedList().addAll(new ArrayList());
```

instead of

```
myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(new ArrayList());
```

If you want add a String in your arrayList you can do the below.

```
myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add("a1");
myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(util.format(resutlMap.get("obj_Id")));
myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(util.format(resutlMap.get("a1_date")));
```

or if you are using Java 9 you can do the below.

```
myJjjModel.getCombinedList().addAll(List.of("a1",util.format(resutlMap.get("obj_Id")),util.format(resutlMap.get("a1_date"))));
```

for **Question 2 :** 
You cannot store multidimensional value in single List. You can use the below in that case.

```
List<List<String>>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using this now:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> combinedList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();    

@Transient
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getCombinedList() {
return combinedList;
}

public void setCombinedList(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> combinedList) {
this.combinedList = combinedList;
}
```

and on action :

```
            ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempList.add(myJjjModel.getObjectid());
            tempList.add(util.format(resutlMap.get("a1_date")));
            tempList.add(util.format(resutlMap.get("obj_Id")));
            myJjjModel.getCombinedList().add(tempList);
```

working fine now.